# Jade Agent Communication: Making the agent reply

Tags: java, agent, agents-jade

I am doing a project MAS project on jade.
I have 2 agents one to send and one to receive.
How do i make agent 1 send a message to agent 2, for example "1000", and only when agent 2 receives the "1000", agent 2 will reply with for example, "turn off"?

Comment: The second tag is JADE not pug. Pug is a node.js HTML templating engine that was formerly called Jade.

Comment: I typed jade but it came out as pug..

Comment: The right tag is `agents-jade`.

Answer (score 0):

My sugestion is to create agent1 with a RequestPerformer behaviour and agent2 with a CyclicBehaviour to listen messages.

agent1 behaviour content can be like this:

```
ACLMessage cfp = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.CFP);
cfp.addReceiver(/*agent2AID*/);

cfp.setContent("1000");
cfp.setConversationId(1000);
cfp.setReplyWith("cfp" + System.currentTimeMillis()); // Unique value
myAgent.send(cfp);
mt = MessageTemplate.and(MessageTemplate.MatchConversationId(targetProduct),
                    MessageTemplate.MatchInReplyTo(cfp.getReplyWith()));
```

agent2 behaviour can be like this:

private class CFPServer extends CyclicBehaviour {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
public void action() {
    MessageTemplate mt = MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.CFP);
    ACLMessage msg = myAgent.receive(mt);
    if (msg != null) {
        // CFP Message received. Process it
        String title = msg.getContent();
        ACLMessage reply = msg.createReply();

        // The requested fruit is NOT available for sale.
        reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
        reply.setContent("turn off");

        myAgent.send(reply);

    } else {
        block();
    }
}
```

}

The related problem is very well discussed and solved in many ways, you can check out the following implementation of a simple Contract Net Protocol where you can find send and reply functions:

https://github.com/clebercbr/tp_cnp/blob/master/src/java/
See that the agent initiator is like agent1 and participant and rejector are like your agent2

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to write a cyclic behaviour for messageReception, it will burn the proc for nothing. A simpleBehaviour with done() at false and a block() in the action() is much more efficient.

Regarding your pb, something like that should work :

```
public class ReceiveMessageBehaviour extends SimpleBehaviour{

       private boolean finished=false;

    /**
     * 
     * This behaviour is a one Shot.
     * It receives a message tagged with an inform performative, print the content in the console and destroy itself if its equal to 1000
     * @param myagent
     */
       public ReceiveMessageBehaviour(final Agent myagent) {
           super(myagent);
       }

       public void action() {
            //1) receive the message
            final MessageTemplate msg Template = MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);          
            final ACLMessage msg = this.myAgent.receive(msgTemplate);
            //2) check its caracts
            if (msg != null && msg.getContent().equals("1000")) {       
                System.out.println(this.myAgent.getLocalName()+"<----Result received from "+msg.getSender().getLocalName()+" ,content= "+msg.getContent());
                this.finished=true;

                //3) answer
                final ACLMessage msg2 = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                msg2.setSender(this.myAgent.getAID());
                msg2.addReceiver(new AID(msg.getSender().getLocalName(), AID.ISLOCALNAME));     
                msg2.setContent("turn off");
                this.myAgent.send(msg2);

            }else{
                block();// the behaviour goes to sleep until the arrival of a new message in the agent's Inbox.
            }
      }

    public boolean done() { return finished;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to these JADE related components. But I would like to add the simplest code that we can use to solve this problem using oneShotBehaviour and Cyclicehaviour.

The following code enables simple communication among two clients.

Agent A-Class:-

```
public class Agent_A extends Agent{
  
    protected void setup(){
    
    System.out.println(getAID().getName()+" is ready.");  
    addBehaviour(new AgentA_SendMessage());
    addBehaviour(new AgentA_ReceiveMessage()); 
    }
    
    public class AgentA_SendMessage extends OneShotBehaviour{
        @Override
        public void action(){
            ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
            msg.addReceiver(new AID("AgentB",AID.ISLOCALNAME));
            msg.setContent("1000");
            send(msg);
        }
    }
    
    public class AgentA_ReceiveMessage extends CyclicBehaviour{
        Scanner scn2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        @Override
        public void action(){
        ACLMessage remsg = myAgent.receive();
            if(remsg!=null){
                String reply = remsg.getContent();
                System.out.println("Reply From "+remsg.getSender()+" :- "+reply);
            }
            else{
            block();
            }
        }
    }
    
  
    
}
```

Agent B Class:-

```
public class Agent_B extends Agent{
    protected void setup(){
    System.out.println("Hello Seller Agent : "+getAID().getName()+" is ready.");
    addBehaviour(new AgentB_ReceiveMessage());
    }
    public class AgentB_ReceiveMessage extends CyclicBehaviour{
    
            @Override
            public void action(){
                ACLMessage remsg = myAgent.receive();
                
                    if(remsg!=null){
                        System.out.println(""+remsg);
                        ACLMessage reply = remsg.createReply();
                        reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.INFORM);
                        String price = remsg.getContent();
                        reply.setContent("off");
                        send(reply);     
                    }else{
                        block();
                    }
            }
    }
}
```